# How to set a environment variable in the current shell with Python?

Tags: python, shell

I want to set an environment variable with a [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) script, influencing the shell I am starting the script in. Here is what I mean

```
python -c "import os;os.system('export TESTW=1')"
```

But the command

```
echo ${TESTW}
```

returns nothing. Also with the expression

```
python -c "import os;os.environ['TEST']='1'"
```

it does not work.

Is there another way to do this in the direct sense? Or is it better to write the variables in a file which I execute from 'outside' of the Python script?

Answer (score 4):

You can influence environment via: [putenv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.putenv) BUT it will not influence the caller environment, only environment of forked children. 
It's really much better to setup environment before launching the python script.

I may propose such variant. You create a bash script and a python script. In bash script you call the python script with params. One param - one env variable. Eg:

```
#!/bin/bash

export TESTV1=$(python you_program.py testv1)
export TESTV2=$(python you_program.py testv2)
```

and `you_program.py testv1` returns value just for one env variable.

Comment: Well, in this context this python script is to be used to setup the environment for something else.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using the solution proposed by chepner and Maxym (where the [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) script provides the values and your shell exports the variables). If that is not an option for you, you could still use `eval` to execute what the python script writes in your current [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) process:

```
eval $( python -c "print('export TESTW=1')" )
```

Caution: `eval` is usually read "evil" in Bash programming. As a general rule of thumb, one should avoid "blindly" executing code that is not fully under one's control. That includes being generated by another program at runtime as in this case. See also Stack Overflow question *[Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220)*.